# Team Target Platform Version

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

Me and my team all use different versions of Windows - Another team member and I use Windows 10 on the Redstone update, another two use the Creators update

For me and the second team member, `WindowsTargetPlatformVersion` = `10.0.15063.0`

For the rest of the team, `WindowsTargetPlatformVersion` = `10.0.16299.0`

Constantly having to change properties of the project gets annoying. Me and the other team member already downloaded the latest Win10 SDK (16299 should work, but it doesn't). What can we do?

Edit for clarity: By "doesn't work", I mean things like `DWORD` and other `#include <Windows.h>` defined items are not accessible (they're unresolved). Changing the version fixes this.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't" work? *How* doesn't it work? Windows should, by and large, still be *Windows*. And it is usually very backwards compatible (for example I can run a 32-bit Windows XP application on a 64-bit Windows 10 system). You have to be much more specific about the problems you have. Perhaps take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: Do you mean that you can not select the new SDK version in the project settings even after installing the SDK? Did you install the SDK through the VS installer? I don't know one way or the other but it wouldn't surprise me if there are settings VS needs from the installer process in order to pick up that the SDK version is present.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It doesn't work as in `#include <Windows.h>` doesn't work and neither do any of the Windows files work.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir I'm sure an SDK was installed through the VS installer, but I also downloaded it straight from the MS website (mainly for WinDBG, but also as something to solve this issue)